# Browser was freeze when i update array items in v-for block

Tags: vue.js

I use [v-autocomplete](https://github.com/paliari/v-autocomplete) component and updating items list after http request. But browser was freeze when i set items. What's wrong?

```
{
    mixins: [search_field_block],
    data: function () {
        return {
            item_component: {
                props: ['item'],
                template: '<div v-html="item.full_name"></div>'
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        search: function (text) {
            this.search_text = text.trim();

            if (this.search_text) {
                this.doGET('/api-method/search_place/', {'query': this.search_text}, this.update_items);
            }
        },
        update_items: function (data) {
            this.items = data;
        }
    }
}
```

I use a mixin for other components. It contained universal template with [v-autocomplete](https://github.com/paliari/v-autocomplete/blob/master/src/Autocomplete.vue):

```
<field-block :label="label" :error="field_error" :description="item_description">
        <v-autocomplete slot="input"
                        class="page-form__field required"
                        :class="{ focused: focused, 'not-empty': not_empty, error: field_error != null, 'list-open': is_list_open }"
                        v-model="value"
                        ref="autocomplete"

                        :required="required"
                        :inputAttrs="{ref: 'input', autocomplete: 'off'}"
                        :items="items"
                        :component-item="item_component"
                        :get-label="getLabel"
                        :min-len="2"
                        @update-items="search"
                        @item-selected="onSelect"
                        @input="onInput"
                        @blur="onBlur"
                        @focus="onFocus">
        </v-autocomplete>
    </field-block>
```

I was find [v-autocomplete](https://github.com/paliari/v-autocomplete/blob/master/src/Autocomplete.vue) on the github. It contain a v-for block for rendering search results

Comment: This does not appear to be a complete code example. The template for the parent component seems to be missing

Comment: Please add the code which contains v-for block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I have "computed" property and set value to parent app:

```
computed: {
            is_list_open: function () {
                this.$parent.list_opened = this.focused && this.items.length > 0 || (this.$refs.autocomplete ? this.$refs.autocomplete.show : false);
                return this.$parent.list_opened;
            }
        },
```

This is incorrect behavior.